# How to unit test a service call in xUnit and nSubstitute

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-core, nunit, nsubstitute

I been trying to figure out how i can unit test service and so far have got nowhere.

I am using xUnit and NSubstitute (as advised by friends), below is the simple test that i want to run (which fails currently).

```
public class UnitTest1
{
    private readonly RallyService _rallyService;

    public UnitTest1(RallyService rallyService)
    {
        _rallyService= rallyService;
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Test1()
    {
        var result = _rallyService.GetAllRallies();

        Assert.Equal(2, result.Count());
    }
}
```

My rally service class makes a simple call to the db to get all Rally entites and returns those:

```
public class RallyService : IRallyService
{
    private readonly RallyDbContext _context;

    public RallyService(RallyDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Rally> GetAllRallies()
    {
        return _context.Rallies;
    }
}
```

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37630564/how-to-mock-up-dbcontext

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you use .NET Core, I assume you also use Entity Framework Core. While it was possible to mock most of the operations in the previous EF version, however the EF Core suggests to use [in-memory database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/in-memory) for unit testing. I.e. you don't need to mock `RallyDbContext`, hence `NSubstitute` is not needed for this particular test. You would need `NSubstitute` to mock the service when testing a controller or application using the service.

Below is your `Test1` written using in-memory database.

```
public class UnitTest1
{
    private readonly DbContextOptions<RallyDbContext> _options;

    public UnitTest1()
    {
        // Use GUID for in-memory DB names to prevent any possible name conflicts
        _options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<RallyDbContext>()
            .UseInMemoryDatabase(Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
            .Options;
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task Test1()
    {
        using (var context = new RallyDbContext(_options))
        {
            //Given 2 records in database
            await context.AddRangeAsync(new Rally { Name = "rally1" }, new Rally { Name = "rally2" });
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        using (var context = new RallyDbContext(_options))
        {
            //When retrieve all rally records from the database
            var service = new RallyService(context);
            var rallies = service.GetAllRallies();

            //Then records count should be 2
            Assert.Equal(2, rallies.Count());
        }
    }
}
```

A working test application with this unit test is in my [GitHub](https://github.com/ignas-sakalauskas/SO47725164) for your reference. I used SQL Express in the actual app.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is standard to have a unit test constructor with a parameter. The unit test runner will new up this class, and unless you are using something that will auto-inject that parameter I think the test will fail to run.

Here is a standard fixture layout:

```
public class SampleFixture {

    [Fact]
    public void SampleShouldWork() {
        // Arrange stuff we need for the test. This may involved configuring
        // some dependencies, and also creating the subject we are testing.
        var realOrSubstitutedDependency = new FakeDependency();
        realOrSubstitutedDependency.WorkingItemCount = 42;
        var subject = new Subject(realOrSubstitutedDependency);

        // Act: perform the operation we are testing
        var result = subject.DoWork();

        // Assert: check the subject's operation worked as expected
        Assert.Equal(42, result);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void AnotherTest() { /* ... */ }
}
```

If you need a common setup between tests, you can use a parameterless constructor and do common initialisation there.

In terms of the specific class you are trying to test, you need to make sure your `RallyDbContext` is in a known state to repeatably and reliably test. You may want to look up answers specific to testing Entity Framework for more information.